# How to use ReportViewer.PrintDialog()

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to use ReportViewer1.PrintDialog() instead of ReportViewer1.Refreshreport()
I mean to take my report to printer, instead of viewing it.

But when I run the code, it generates error.

The error is

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Please advise what is the problem?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: The problem is that you have not told us the error...

Comment: Error is "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the report is already in the process of rendering when you call PrintDialog(). You have to wait for the rendering to complete in order to avoid this error. You can use the [RenderComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.renderingcomplete%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method to detect when the report is done rendering and it is safe to call PrintDialog().

Comment: Had the exact same issue as above.  This was definitely the cause.  Thanks!